# php composer class not found when library is installed

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm quite new to using composer and I am not too sure what I am doing at this point. I am currently trying to use this [Nmap](https://packagist.org/packages/willdurand/nmap) library I found. now once I have this library installed using this command`composer require willdurand/nmap`
 I created a index.php file with

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$hosts = Nmap::create()->scan([ 'example.com' ]);

$ports = $hosts->getOpenPorts();

echo $ports;

?>
```

This is what my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "willdurand/nmap": "^0.5.0"
    }
}
```

When I run this I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Nmap' not found in /var/www/html/nmap.php:5`. I have Nmap installed on my Unix system. Any help on this issue would be great.

Comment: `Nmap` class is under `Nmap` namespace, you need to add `use Nmap\Nmap;` under your require line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not define a current namespace, PHP looks for any references classes in the root namespace. However, it cannot find `Nmap` in the root namespace because it is [defined in the ´Nmap´ namespace](https://github.com/willdurand/nmap/blob/master/src/Nmap/Nmap.php#L11).

You have to either add the namespace to the class defenition:

```
$hosts = \Nmap\Nmap::create()->scan([ 'example.com' ]);
```

Or, add a using statement for this class at the top of your file: (under `<?php` ofcourse)

```
use Nmap\Nmap;
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me that makes a lot of sense now and it works!!